# Why do i get antiverus alert when use smtp & GetAsyncKeyState

Tags: c#, winforms

I got antivirus alert tor\gen8 spy when I build

here is my code :

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace reading
{
   public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
  public Form1()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
   }
  [DllImport("user32.dll")]
  private static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(System.Windows.Forms.Keys vKey);

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtpClient;
}

}
}
```

I don't have virus I'am sure the alert appear just when I build I try to create new project and it's give me the same result , but when I remove ( System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient ) or ( GetAsyncKeyState) It's build succuffly , If any one help me to compile the same code .

Any suggestion?

And thanks for help

Comment: We don't help with programming questions here at Superuser.

Answer (score 0):

Because `GetAsyncKeyState` is a common way that keyloggers use. And usually they send the data via e-mail.

You have to capture keys in another way, but surely it will be detected as keylogger too. If you program is not a Keylogger there will be a workaround surely.